# Trying to draw Venn diagram of $A\cup(B\cap C\cap D)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

how would you draw $A\cup(B\cap C\cap D)$
I tried with paint doesn't look good and I don't know if there are tools to make this easier would appreciate any help or tips

[image]

Comment: Assuming that $A \cap (B \cup C \cup D) = \emptyset$ and $B \cap C \cap D \ne \emptyset$, your drawing is fine. Is your question about what software to use?

Comment: yeah because I want to combine them into 1

Comment: I Think It is possible to draw 4 circles which intersect each other then show the region

Comment: It's hard to draw venn diagrams with more than three sets.  If we don't know how $A$ interacts with $B,C,D$ you should draw $A$ so it intersects with the sets $B,C,D$ which requires a rather curvy twisty edge.  Which is why it is hard to draw venn diagrams with more than $3$ sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[draw.io](https://www.draw.io/) has templates for Venn diagrams. [This](https://omics.pnl.gov/software/venn-diagram-plotter) tool may prove useful. [This](https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_best_software_for_drawing_a_VENN_diagram) discussion contains links to several tools one can use to draw Venn diagrams.

Personally, I have used a python library called [pyvenn](https://github.com/tctianchi/pyvenn) which allows plotting Venn diagrams containing up to $6$ different sets.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using ellipses (Check that there are indeed 16 regions) for the delimitation of your areas ; then use the "fill" device of your drawing tool to fill in the good areas.

[image]

Remark : you can tilt the diagram 45° for a better ease at drawing your ellipses.

Comment: @Santana Afton All right, I add it (use the "fill" device).